# How can I set up a The Ship server?

Tags: steam, server-administration, the-ship

As I stated in the title, how can I set up a server for [*The Ship*](http://www.blazinggriffin.com/the-ship-murder-party)? I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find guides of any kind anywhere. There's some basic guides on how to set up a *steamcmd* server, but I'm still completely lost.

So my question.

- What ports do I need to forward so that my friends may play the ship with me?
- What steps do I need to take in order to download a functional version of *The Ship* server from *steamcmd*
- What steps do I need to take in order to get the server running once it has been downloaded?

Any help would be appreciated as there is apparently zero documentation floating around out there currently.

Comment: Hey Dante, I suggest using a program like LogMeIn Hamachi or Tunggle, which avoids the whole port forwarding issue by simulating you and your friends on the same LAN. As for the rest, I'll leave that to someone who knows The Ship.

Comment: I'm trying to set one up and I'm getting completely confused. As you've managed to set one up, can you share some help? I've tried downloading the dedicated server and setting up a server in-game, both methods are giving my servers IP as my internal IP rather than my external IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on tombull89's answer, the default ship port is actually 27015 UDP.

Also, to run the ship after downloading it, you will actually need to `cd` to the directory and run (on Windows)

```
srcds.exe -console -game ship
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have to own The Ship to download the server, so I cannot test this, but from what I know/can find, this should work. I am assuming you are running Windows.

**Port** - try 27016.

**SteamCMD**

1. Download SteamCMD from
   [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD).
2. Extract/Start SteamCMD and let it download the files to update itself.
3. Once SteamCMD has updated, type in `login <username>` where username is your Steam account and press enter.
4. Then enter your account password. If you have Steam dual-authentication enabled you will need to check your email for the account code.
5. Next, set the install location - at the Steam> prompt, type `force_install_dir <path_to_install>` eg force_install_dir C:\theship.
6. After, run the `app_update 2403` command.
7. When it finishes download the files, type `quit` at the command line to quit steamcmd.

**Running Server** - go to wherever you downloaded the files to (eg C:\theship) and find the server .exe in that folder. Run it, and see if you can connect to it from your computer.

Comment: 27016... UDP, I assume?